# firebase does not save in the same array

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

firebase does not save in the same array
i want to save in the same array not generate a new name

my code:`

```
dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}`).once("value").then(async function(db) {
  if (db.val() == null) {
    dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}`).set({
      user: ["jhon"] //mensagem: [`${message.content} | ${message.guild.name} | ${message.channel.name} | ${ping.getUTCHours()}:${ping.getUTCMinutes()}:${ping.getUTCSeconds()}  ${ping.getUTCDate()}/${ping.getUTCMonth() + 1}/${ping.getFullYear()} | ${message.guild.vanityURLCode}`], 
    }); // Cano o autor não esteja no sistema de xp, ele vai setar um parametro no banco de dados com o xp e level
  } else {
    dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}/mensagem`).push({
      user: ["lety"]
    });

  };
});
```

The output is:

`23011393: mensagem: user: 0 :"jhon" -NGWqzRmWl8H4C6FEJ5L: user: 0: "lety"`

I want to save in the same array "user" not generate a new name

Comment: Can you edit your question and add your database sample as JSON (there's an export button in Firebase console)? A screenshot of what the result should look like will also help.

Comment: yes: output: https://prnt.sc/5VdBo_Ntth1p

Comment: sim eu quero lety sob jhon

Comment: If I understand correctly, the "lety" must be under "john"?

Comment: yes i want lety under jhon

Comment: but it's creating another string, and I've already changed Usersmsg/${message.author.id}/mensagem to Usersmsg/${message.author.id}

Comment: but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The `push()` adds a new node to specified path. You'll need to specify index in the array to add an item like this:

```
dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}`).once("value").then(async function(snap) {
  if (snap.val() == null) {
    await dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}`).set({
      user: ["jhon"]
    });
  } else {
    await dbmsg.ref(`Usersmsg/${message.author.id}/user`).update({
      1: "lety"
    });
  };
});
```

You can get current count of users in that array like this:

```
const count = Object.keys(snap.val()).length
```

Comment: how do i pass var count for update?

Comment: example: count: "lety"

Comment: this returns does not return the variable but a name in the db